# A variable in an anonymous function under EventListener staying undefined despite being previously declared and then defined clearly

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So I'm making a basic to-do list using only HTML and JS and for some reason, when I go to add an item to the list, the variable that I'm using to select the empty "li" element is returning as "undefined" after I execute the function under the EventListener for the "clear" button. Could someone help out here pls. HTML and JS attached below:

```js
let todos = [];
let add = document.querySelector("#add");
let remove = document.querySelector("#remove")
let clear = document.querySelector("#clear")
let todolist = document.querySelector("#todolist")
let addTodo;
let clearedTodo;
let newTodo;

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  addTodo = prompt("Enter the item you would like to add.")
  todos.push(addTodo);
  todolist.innerHTML += "<li></li>"
  newTodo = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[todos.length - 1]
  newTodo.textContent = addTodo;

})

remove.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let removeTodo = prompt("Enter the index number of the item you would like to remove.") - 1;
  let removedTodo = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[removeTodo]
  removedTodo.remove();
  todos.splice(removeTodo, 1);
})

clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
  todos = [];
  document.querySelector("ol").remove();
  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += '<ol id="todolist"></ol>'
  console.log("To Do list was cleared.")
})
```

```html
<h1>The Ultimate To Do List</h1>
<p>Click on an item to mark as done.</p>

<button id="add">ADD</button>
<button id="remove">REMOVE</button>
<button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
<div id="clearer">
  <ol id="todolist">
  </ol>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your clear function. Mostly it looks good except for one problem that causes the major error. When you remove all the "ol" element, your `todolist` var loses reference, since it has nothing to point to. You would have to redeclare it.

But there is an easier way to fix this. Remove these lines:

```
document.querySelector("ol").remove();
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += '<ol id="todolist"></ol>'
```

Use this line instead:

```
todolist.innerHTML = "";
```

Now the todo list in the DOM is also cleared and your `todolist` var still points to what its supposed to.